# Не работает авторизация через ВКонтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Если кому-то понадобится, вот уже готовый код:

Где то на сайте делаем ссылку (вместо звездочек ваш сайт)

```
<a href="<ваш сайт>/auth.php" class="text_decoration_none footer_20 footer_p">Авторизация через ВКонтакте</a>
```

Создаем страницу auth.php и вносим в неё следующий код:

```
<?
define("APP_ID",'****'); //ID приложения
define("APP_SECRET",'**************'); //Защищённый ключ
define("REDIRECT_URI",'http://****.ru/auth.php'); //Доверенный redirect URI, там, где лежит этот файл

if(!isset($_GET['code'])) { //Получение code 
    $url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=".APP_ID."&scope=offline&redirect_uri=".REDIRECT_URI."&response_type=code&v=5.73"; 
    header("Location:".$url);
    exit(); 
} else {    // получение $token
    $result = false;
    $params = array(
        'client_id' => APP_ID,
        'client_secret' => APP_SECRET,
        'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    );
    $token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?'.urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);

    if (isset($token['access_token'])) { // получение информации о юзере
        $params = array(
            'user_ids' => $token['user_id'],
            'fields'  => 'first_name,last_name,nickname,screen_name,sex,bdate,city,country,timezone,photo,photo_medium,photo_big,has_mobile,rate,contacts,education,online,counters',
            'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
            'v' => '5.73'
        );        
        $get_params = http_build_query($params);                
        $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));

        // информация о юзере
        $bdate = $result -> response[0] -> bdate;    
        $first_name = $result -> response[0] -> first_name;    
        $last_name = $result -> response[0] -> last_name;   
        $photo_medium = $result -> response[0] -> photo_medium;
    } else {
        exit('Ошибка');
    }

    // вывод информации о юзере
    if ($result) {
        echo '<br />';
        echo "ID : " . $params[user_ids] . '<br />';
        echo "Имя пользователя: " . $first_name . '<br />';
        echo "ф пользователя: " . $last_name . '<br />';
        echo "День Рождения: " . $bdate . '<br />';
        echo '<img src="' . $photo_medium . '" />'; echo "<br />";
    }
}
if($_GET['error']) {
   exit($_GET['error_description']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом вопросе уже код исправлен на рабочий, если кому то надо, забирайте.

Answer (score 3):

Ранее, если Вы не указывали в своём запросе параметр v (версию), он автоматически считался равным 3.0. Теперь параметр v с номером версии стал обязательным для всех запросов к API, всех, включая авторизацию.

Сервер вернет ошибку 8 на запрос, в котором не содержится этот параметр. Если методы в Вашем приложении стали возвращать ошибку invalid request на любой запрос или сломалась авторизация — укажите используемую версию API для возобновления работы.

Обратите внимание: мы не рекомендуем использовать в запросах номера версий ниже 5.0, поскольку старые версии (включая 3.0 и 4.0) в будущем перестанут поддерживаться.

Более подробно об этих изменениях мы писали здесь: https://vk.com/dev/version_update

То есть сейчас вам нужно добавить в массивы $params

```
'v' => '5.73'
```

Comment: дело было не в этом, но за эту правку спасибо

Answer (score 0):

У меня аналогичная ошибка возникла, поскольку VK поменял поле с id с **uid** на просто **id**.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо этого участка кода:

```
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?&v=3.0' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
```

Надо:

```
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?&v=3.0' .'?'. urldecode(http_build_query($params));
```